# How to check input array shapes in Keras?

Tags: keras

Here is the model.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((3,150,150), input_shape=(150,150,3)))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
print(model.output_shape)
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu'))
print model.output_shape


(None, 5, 152, 150)
(None, 3, 150, 64)
```

And when I try and feed in data, I get this

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_35 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 1)
```

Output shape doesn't seem to be giving me what the layer is seeing. The layer is seeing (32,1) while output shape is printing the correct 4 dimensional (None(about to be 32 with the batch size), 3,150,64)

What am I doing wrong? Why is this shape (32,1)?

Answer (score 0):

Your data does not have 4 dimensions, your data has shape (32,1).

Your model, on the other hand is expecting data with 4 dimensions: (None, 3, 150, 64).

The output shape of your model must be the same shape of your data (Y).

Use model.summary to see all shapes at once.

Comment: this shows the shape of the layer, but it doesn't show the shape of the data itself. I am passing in images. How could they be (32,1)? This is why I want to inspect the data array as its being passed in. 32 is the batch size, but why is it down to just 1? Oh perhaps these are the outputs - y instead of X..

Comment: Yes, it's the output, called "target" by keras. You need to make your model end up with this shape. You can do that, for instance, by adding a `Flatten()` and a "Dense(1)" layer at the end. (Watch out for the activation functions, they must also match your target).

Comment: ah ok. Is there a way to check the shape of the target data as its being fed in? So that I can confirm that it matches the output_shape of the model?

Comment: How are you feeding data? The shape of the output data you have is (32,1). If it's a numpy array you can just do "mydata.shape".

Comment: its with keras .flow_from_directory. https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/